# asp:RadioButtonList doesn't set correct selected item on load

Tags: asp.net, controls, c#-3.0

I have this code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblExpDate" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="No expiration date"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Expires on:"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

that I would like to be always, on page load, to mark the first option ("no expiration date").
However, if the user marks the second option and reloads, the second option is selected, even though I do this on page load:

```
rblExpDate.Items[0].Selected = true;
rblExpDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you please include your codebehind page?

Comment: I can't - it's a huge page. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I chose is in Javascript (mootools):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
         $("rblExpDate_0").checked = true;
});
```

(I gave up on the .net side)

thanks for your help @Slavo and @Daniel Dyson.

Answer (score 1):

call this function on onload of body tag

```
<body bottomMargin=0 leftMargin=0 topMargin=25 onload=aa() rightMargin=0>
```

under the head tag

```
<script language=Javascript>
function aa() {document.forms[0].item('rblExpDate')[1].disabled=true;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I discovered on Page `PostBack` that my `radioButtonList` was still keeping all previous `ListItems selected property`. Basically, the last item of the `RadioButtonList` that was previously selected will show up as the item selected on your page. So, in your case, once the user selects the 2nd item, that item has the property `checked=checked` despite your code to set the 1st item as selected. Take a look at your View Page Source, you'll see both ListItems being checked.

My solution: on `PagePostBack` set the other `ListItem Selected propety` value to false like this:

```
rblExpDate.Items[0].Selected = true;
rblExpDate.Items[1].Selected = false;
```

This will remove the Checked property on the 2nd item.

Hope that helps someone. Maybe someone has a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your code  is not within a postback check?

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rblExpDate.Items[0].Selected = true;
            rblExpDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

More to the point, this sounds like a strange requirement that doesn't sound very useable. Why have an option available if you are always going to override it?

Comment: Daniel, the thing is that if the second option is checked, I enable a datepicker - and the requirement is that the datepicker will be disabled if the first option is selected.

Comment: In this case, enable or disable the datepicker in the PreRender event. Then make any changes you like to the state of the rbl

Comment: I can disable the datepicker but it still won't let me change the state of the rbl... I need a way to set its selected index.

Answer (score 0):

What most probably happens is that the code executed on Page_Load runs first, setting the element you want. After that the SelectedIndexChanged event of the RadioButtonList fires and gets the selected item from the ViewState, overriding what the code did. You have to debug this, though.

Comment: ViewState is checked during page load so this is unlikely to be the issue here. Nir is setting the values OnLoad, which is after the page has loaded and ViewState has been checked